# Differentiate $y = {(x + 2)^3}{(1 - \sin 2x)^2}{(1 + \tan x)^3}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I haven't got very far in attempting this:

$\eqalign{
  & y = {(x + 2)^3}{(1 - \sin 2x)^2}{(1 + \tan x)^3}  \cr 
  & y = {\left( {(x + 2)(1 + \tan x)} \right)^3}{(1 - \sin 2x)^2} \cr} $

I'm stuck on what to do after this, I dont even know how to begin to differentiate this. Im not sure on whether to use the product rule, the chain rule, differentiate each bracket separately and multiply at the end, or what? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a version of the product rule for > 2 factors.  See one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier first log the expression:
$$
L f(x) = 3 \log(x+2) + 3 \log(1-\sin 2x) + 3 \log (1+\tan x)
$$
After you differentiate what you get is 
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\varphi(x)
$$
Hence your derivative will be 
$$
f'(x)=f(x) \varphi(x)
$$

Comment: @Alex I see, and what is the reasoning behind this, how would I know what situations to apply this to in the future?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks Andre, I missed this part

Comment: @Assad the reason behind this is the property of differntiation of log function: $(\log f(x))'_x = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Comment: @Assad: Apply this to a messy product, which includes quotients, like $\frac{(1+3x)^{17}e^{-x^2}(2+\sin x)^3}{(1+x+x^2)^5}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let be $f,g, w: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. For the diferentiate we have:

$$
(f\cdot g \cdot w)'=f'gz+fg'z+fgz'
$$

solution of the given example is:

$y'=[(x+2)^3(1−\sin2x)^2(1+\tan x)^3]'=[(x+2)^3]'(1−\sin2x)^2(1+\tan x)^3+(x+2)^3[(1−\sin2x)^2]'(1+\tan x)^3+(x+2)^3(1−\sin2x)^2[(1+\tan x)^3]'=3(x+2)^2(1−\sin2x)^2(1+\tan x)^3-(x+2)^3 4\cos2x(1−\sin2x)(1+\tan x)^3+(x+2)^3(1−\sin2x)^2\frac{3}{\cos^2 x}(1+\tan x)^2$

Now you  can only get if you want to simplify.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I think the product rule for > 2 factors is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your direct question, you would have to use all of the differentiation rules you proposed.  A first pass through the product (with the Product Rule and Chain Rule) would look like:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} \ =  3 ( x + 2 )^2 \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x + 2) \cdot (1 - \sin 2x)^2 (1 + \tan x)^3  $$

$$ + \ (x + 2)^3 \cdot 2( 1 - \sin 2x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (1 - \sin 2x) \cdot (1 + \tan x)^3  $$

$$ + \ (x + 2)^3 \cdot (1 - \sin 2x)^2 \cdot 3 (1 + \tan x)^2 \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (1 + \tan x) ,$$

with, of course, the Chain Rule still to be carried out on the factor $\frac{d}{dx} (1 - \sin 2x)$ .  Then simplify the terms, extract common factors, and simplify the final expression.  It is for this reason that we apply logarithmic differentiation, as described in Alex's post.